# Run Google Sheets script on multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a Google Sheets script that's designed to input timestamps whenever there is an edit, but I need it to run on multiple sheets (West, East AND North) on the same drive... How can I make that work?

See the code below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  //1.Change 'Sheet1' to be matching your sheet name
  if (r.getColumn() < 9 && ss.getName()=='WEST') { // 2. If Edit is done in any column before Column (L)  And sheet name is WEST then:    
var celladdress ='L'+ r.getRowIndex() 
    ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing one line of your code with this

```
if (r.getColumn() < 9 && ( ss.getName()=='WEST' || ss.getName()=='EAST' || ss.getName()=='NORTH' || ss.getName()=='SOUTH' ) ) {
```

It's a bit long, but it follows your current logic.